Google Forms: limiting number of questions answered
I using Google Forms to build a kind of voting form, I have 5 books with a linear scale so users can vote from 1-10.
but I want to limit the vote to only 2 books, if users vote or answer more or less than 2 then I want Google Forms not to let the user submit until they, only answer 2 questions.

for example in the above picture you can only rate 2 books of your choice but no more/less than 2.
